# os.walk doesn't work in linux volume (python 2.7)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, unix, os.walk

**Looking for some specific directory path in Linux volume. If it matches, then store the path in a list called sb_dir. If path already in sb_dir, no need to iterate through that path. Following code works perfectly fine in MacOSX which is my local. But doesn't work in Linux. Tried using "glob" library but glob doesn't iterate through all the directories, subdirectories, files like os.walk. (Using python 2.7)

Is it a character encoding issue - "utf-8"? if yes, how to solve it?

If I use glob module... how can I iterate through all the directories, sub-directories, files in linux?**

```
import re, os
sb_dir = []
existing = set()
def list_of_dirs(*args):
    path =''.join(args)
    for root, subdir, files in os.walk((path), topdown=True):
        if re.findall("rel_\d\d.*(?=\-)-\d{8}.\d", root) or re.findall(
                "pub-\d{8}.\d", root):
            if any(root.startswith(r) for r in existing):
                continue

            existing.add(root + os.sep)
            sb_dir.append(root)
    return sb_dir

print(list_of_dirs(*argv[1:]))
```

Comment: Can you show us how this program is executed (including arguments), and a directory listing of the files that you expect to be found?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/9a4eae6dea6e186acf26a69a6e56898b

Comment: `NameError: name 'argv' is not defined`

Comment: May I ask - how did you run the script? It should be: python script.py /Users/username